# Import module function to the root - python

Tags: python

I have a package where am doing this:

```
from p1 import p1
p1.cos(5)
```

But, would like to write instead:

```
import p1
p1.cos(5)
```

(like numpy)

How can I modify `p1/__init__.py` to get this "writing" enabled ?

Comment: please provide the structure of your scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible or either a good idea; using `from p1 import p1` tells explicity what you import. Who reads `import p1` assumes you import the module, not a specific function from it. **readability counts.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have files like

```
. 
`-- p1
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- p1.py
```

and you define `cos` in `p1.py` 
then in `p1/__init__.py` you could put

```
from .p1 import cos
```

if `cos` comes from somewhere else then just have `p1/__init__.py` import it from wherever as appropriate.  E.g. in `p1/__init__.py` you could just as easily put

```
from math import cos
```

Comment: This would import cos from p1 to the importing code. What happens to the rest of the module? is it imported as well?

Comment: It depends on what you actually put into `p1/__init__.py`.  Each name you import or assign there will become part of the `p1` module.  If you're selective then `p1` will end up with only a few things but if in `p1/__init__.py` you do something sloppy like `from xxx import *` then p1 will end up with a lot.

Comment: @jq170727 so let's say in your example, assuming there are no more definitions in `p1/__init__.py` - when I do `import p1` it imports **only** p1.cos to the namespace? nothing else from the module?

Comment: `import p1` adds one thing to the namespace: `p1`.  Here is an experiment you can do:  `bash-3.2$ python
>>> locals()` you should see `{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}` then do `>>> import p1 >>> locals()` then you will see `{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'p1': <module 'p1' from 'p1/__init__.pyc'>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}`

Answer (score -1):

Tensor

How about:

```
import p1
p1.p1.cos(5)
```

or

```
from p1 import *
p1.cos(5)
```